# Implementing a decorator to limit setters

Tags: python, oop

I have a class with a handful of instance variables, which I set through functions decorated with the `@someinstancevariable.setter` decorators. How would I go about ensuring that the values set have a maximum and a minimum value to which they could be set? And would I need to have multiple decorators for this or is there some way I can use the regular `@someinstancevariable.setter` decorator and override it?

Comment: It sounds like you want a custom descriptor; have you read https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5842593/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `property` is really a specific implementation of a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), and you can roll your own:

```
class ValidRange(object):

    def __init__(self, name, min_, max_):
        self._min = min_
        self._max = max_
        self._name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self._name)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, self._name, min(self._max, max(value, self._min)))

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        delattr(instance, self.name)
```

This would be used like:

```
>>> class Weather(object):
...     temperature = ValidRange('_temp', 0, 100)
... 
>>> w = Weather()
>>> w.temperature = 120
>>> w.temperature
100
```

I've posted a fancier descriptor method [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/98892/32391) with automagical `name`-setting...

Comment: Brilliant. Got to love it when there's a simpler solution!